# applying the same command to multiple files in multiple subdirectories

Tags: python, bash, fastq

I have a directory with 94 subdirectories, each containing one or two files `*.fastq`. I need to apply the same python command to each of these files and produce a new file `qc_*.fastq`.

I know how to apply a bash script individually to each file, but I'm wondering if there is a way to write a bash script to apply the command to all the files at once

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you think this would look like.  Do you mean you would run a bash script in the top-level directory that traverses down into the subdirectories?

Answer (score 3):

Use find:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.fastq" -exec python script {} \;
```

`.`: The top-most directory

`-type f`: Only files

`-iname "*.fastq"`: File name ends in `.fastq` (case insensitive)

`-exec python script`: The command you want to execute.

Comment: Awesome thanks! the find commands works great, but is there a python variable I can use to add the qc_ prefix to the output file?

Comment: That would obviously depend on what your python script is actually doing. You might be able to just do `-exec python script {} > qc_file.fastq \;`.

Comment: Actually the above wouldn't work for what you want. It would depend on your script.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `find . -name "*.fastq" | xargs your_bash_script.sh`, which use `find` to get all the files and apply your script to each one of them.